# Using html themes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

First of all I want to express that I am quite new with ReactJS and this question might be not very appropriate to the topic but i am just trying to enrich my knowledge about it.

I have a html/css theme and I am trying to build a application using that theme but with reactjs. Is there any way to use that theme in react?

I have used several ui libraries to create some application with react but from scratch. What would be the solution when I already have a html/css theme to use in my project with react?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the theme relies on jQuery it can be hard, a replace in project for `class="` to `className="` should be enough.

Comment: I understand. but do i have to manually copy all the codes into my react application?